# How can I change the statusBarStyle when use searchBar

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, statusbar

I just want to change the statusBarStyle when I use the searchBar.and I try in this way. But it didn't work? So, how can I achieve it ?

```
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    if searchController.active == true {
        return UIStatusBarStyle.Default
    }
    else {
        return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation is set to true, then it is fairly difficult. If it is false then the normal method works.